# $http.jsonp is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I have following $http call in controller:

see complete code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmloaFd0r8ts50h1la0M?p=preview)

```
$http.jsonp("http://currencyconverter.kund.nu/api/availablecurrencies/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
  .success(function(data){
    console.log('data',data)
  })
  .error(function(err){
    console.log('err',err)//it console err undefined
  })
```

above code console `err undefined`. means it executing error callback.but when i open chrome network tool, in responses it is showing response data.Why it is like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your jsonp url should always have one parameter `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` which you are missing here

```
$http.jsonp("http://currencyconverter.kund.nu/api/availablecurrencies/?callbak=JSON_CALLBACK")
```

**Update**

Seems like server side you had not implemented the logic to wrap returned object inside value of callback, because hit [this url](http://currencyconverter.kund.nu/api/availablecurrencies/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK) in browser console should give array wrap inside `JSON_CALLBACK` variable

```
JSON_CALLBACK({..data here})
```

But it is returning an array

```
[...data...]
```

This behavior should be handled on server side.

Comment: mistakely i have written ?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK instead of ?callbak=JSON_CALLBACK". but again it is nt working.

Comment: yes, but i am using other's (public) api.i can't modify this. is there a way to handle cross domain issue ?